# How to get a normalized font size for a PDF using PDFBox

Tags: parsing, pdf, pdfbox

I am working on a project that parses pdf files and extracts text. I am using the TextPosition class to generate a data-structure containing the position and size of each character in the pdf file.

I am running into an issue where there is a custom defined Type 3 font inside the pdf with really large characters. Font that appears to be about font size 9 on the screen are actually set to a font size of 0.24. I attempted to try and use the fontDescriptor to try and get the cap height of the font and use that instead, but it is null. Also, there is another font on the page that has a large amount of white-space above and below it, making the Cap height unusable. Here is what the TextPosition class looks like for a random character on the page.

[image]

I was hoping that someone knew how to get the correct pt font size?

Thanks

Comment: Please also look at the `textMatrix` - it might be set to scale the text.

Comment: the `textMatrix` is `[0.24,0.0,0.0,0.24,157.6,773.5]` . Which just sets the scale to 0.24

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question?

Comment: "making the Cap height unusable" - these values are often not reliable, sadly.